# Why does the IP 10.0.2.2 not work from Android emulator

Tags: rest, cordova, android-emulator

I am new on android phonegap app. I tried to buld a login via rest api from android emulator app, but always it ended up in jquery ajax error function, I have used the IP address 10.0.2.2 but still it is not working - how could I get success response of jquery ajax from android emulator. Here I am giving the js code ..

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'http://10.0.2.2/wedding/Source/Website/api/login',
          type: 'POST',
          data: $('#loginPageForm').serialize(),
          success: function(data){
             /*Process your response here*/
              alert(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(99999);
          }
       });


                   And here is the html form I am using for login ...

<form method="post" data-ajax="false" id="loginPageForm">
         <fieldset>
             <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                 <label for="basic">Username:</label>
                 <input type="text" name="User[username]" id="loginPageUsername" value=""  />
             </div>
             <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                 <label for="basic">Password:</label>
                 <input type="password" name="User[password]" id="loginPagePassword" value=""  />
             </div>
             <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                 <button value="Login" name="loginPageSubmit" type="button" onClick="doLogin()">Login</button>
             </div>
         </fieldset>
     </form>
```

I have test the rest app via rest client that working properly and then I also tested the app on browser that is also working on, but the same code is not working on Android emulator.Can anyone please explain a bit where is the mistake and what do I need to do to fix it.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Did you bother looking at the error? It may tell you something important.

Comment: Yes, actually I put an alert(jqXHR.responseTest) but that was blank, so I was confused then I put alert(9999) to be assured that it has been ended up at error response of ajax

Comment: sorry I misspelled the alert that was alert(jqXHR.responseText)

Comment: Try alerting the errorThrown and statusCode.

Comment: I tried alerting this
    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText+'pppp'+XMLHttpRequest.statusCode);

but that return responseText blank and statusCode return a function definition,  something like this ....function(){if(a){var b; 
}}

Comment: Why did you alert XMLHttpRequest.statusCode instead of just plain statusCode? Look at your error handler: error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown).

Comment: I tried alerting this
    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText+'pppp'+XMLHttpRequest.statusCode);

but that return responseText blank and statusCode return a function definition,  something like this ....function(){if(a){var b; if(s , 2 for(b in a)j[b] = [j[b], a[b]]; else b = a[v.staus], v.then(b, b)} return this;})
}}

Comment: Yes, the parameter "textStatus" in error handler is returning "error" - any idea what is wrong ?